# The left-hand side of an assignment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making game in unity, and trying to make an android swipe control system. It is the same as in toutorial, but somehow it return error for me - "Error    CS0131  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer". How can I make this code work?

```
bool isDraging = false;
Vector2 startTouch, swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;

if (isDraging)
{
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position = startTouch; 
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        (Vector2)Input.mousePosition = startTouch = swipeDelta;    
}
```

Comment: As you can see [from the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html), `mousePosition` is **read-only**, so you can't assign to it in the `else if` branch. This strikes me as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you actually trying to solve? There's likely a better way of going about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to change the `mousePosition`. Unity Game Engine does not have the ability to change the `mousePosition`. To accomplish this you need to use the [system.windows.forms.cursor.position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx). To do this you need to add the windows.form.dll to the assembly of your project. To do this download the dll into the Unity asset folder and at the beginning of your code add:

```
using dllNamespace
```

Note dllNamespace is the namespace of your dll.